# Getting the sub-classes of an interface

Tags: java, interface, hashmap, key

I am working on a project in Java, and we have a HashMap that is made up of an interface and integer, (HashMap<Item, Integer>()), and now I need to check that hashmap for a specific class that implements the interface. Specifically, I need to see if the "inventory" hashmap holds a sword (which is a class that implements Item) and if the inventory does have a Sword then it can carry out a specific method. Is there a way to return the specific class that implements my item interface?

Comment: Can’t you just check the HashMap keys using `instanceof`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashMap`s use the `hashCode` method of its key. `Item.class.hashCode()` is different from `Sword.class.hashCode()`. So no, it is not possible to achieve constant-time, O(1) lookup. Perhaps you need to change your design.

The only way I can think of to check if your map contains a `Sword` as key is to use a loop:

```
for (final Item key : map.keySet()) {
  if (key instanceof Sword) {
    // your map contains a sword
  }
}
```

Comment: Furthermore, in Java 16+, that `instanceof` test can also perform a cast implicitly. See [*JEP 394: Pattern Matching for `instanceof`*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394). Example: `if ( key instanceof Sword sword ) { … use sword var here … }`